# Can not Integrate Advance Search Tree View to Module Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, odoo-12, odoo-14

I'm Odoo Beginner

I try to integrate third party app (Advance Search View ver 12) to my Odoo ver14. But after install app I can not see any change in my Module. Expect as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y11DS.png

Please let me know where should I config . Thank you

Comment: First of all, you try to install a V12 third party app on a V14 base. This is already a potentially problematic situation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check that the technical name of the module is in DB.
Settings -> Technical -> Model (debug mode)